# MyBatis inserts one to many relationship

Tags: insert, one-to-many, mybatis

I have my very simple one `(Question)` to many `(Options)` relationship, Option has the FK `(questionId)` to Question, now I'm going to insert a Question object with a list of Options inside within one XML configuration.

Question:

```
public Class Question{
    ...
    private Integer questionId;
    private List<Option> options;
    ....
}
```

Option:

```
public Class Option{
   ...
   private Integer optionId;
   private String context;

   private Integer questionId; //FK

   ....
}
```

The configuration:

```
...

<insert id="insertQuestion" parameterType="com.pojos.Question" useGeneratedKeys="true">

        INSERT into question (...) VALUES (...);

        <selectKey keyColumn="questionId" keyProperty="questionId" resultType="int">
            SELECT MAX(questionId) FROM question;
        </selectKey>

        INSERT INTO option (context, questionId)
        VALUES
            <foreach collection="options" item="option" open="(" separator="),(" close=")">
                #{option.context}, #{questionId}
            </foreach>
    </insert>

...
```

As you can see, I'd like to use the just auto-generated `questionId` as the FK info for the options, however it doesn't work through, how can I make it work? or I cannot put them into a single  scope?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In java 8 you could use `default` interface methods. 
First you need to separate the operation with something like this:

- Main table:

  ```
  INSERT into question (...) VALUES (...);

  <selectKey keyColumn="questionId" keyProperty="questionId" resultType="int">
      SELECT MAX(questionId) FROM question;
  </selectKey>
  ```

- One to many relationship

  ```
  INSERT INTO option (context, questionId)
  VALUES
      <foreach collection="options" item="option" open="(" separator="),(" close=")">
          #{option.context}, #{questionId}
      </foreach>
  ```

Then in your interface you will have at least three methods: `insertQuestion`, `insertQuestionOptions` and the default method (you could call it `insertQuestionWithOptions` for example) which uses both methods to insert it.

```
public interface QuestionDao {

    int insertQuestion(Question question);

    int insertOptions(List<Option> options);

    default int insertQuestionsWithOptions(Question question) {
        insertQuestion(question);
        insertOptions(question.getOptions());
   }
}
```

So, now you can use the method `insertQuestionsWithOptions(Question question)` which will insert question and options one to many relationship.